# What is the advantage of passing by reference to shared_ptr over passing by reference directly

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

```
class myMem{};

class Test{
public:
  initMem1(myMem& mInput){/*initialize _mem1*/}
  initMem2(shared_ptr<myMem> &pmInput){/*initialize _mem2*/}

  myMem _mem1;
  shared_ptr<myMem> _mem2;
};

Test myTest;
myTest()
```

So, in the code above, members belong to a class. One member is a value type and another member is a shared_ptr type. Which way is better for a class member? Moreover, I also have the functions to initialize the members. Which way is better?

In general what is the advantage of passing by reference to shared_ptr over passing by reference directly?

Comment: ...one requires you have a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: The Question should be: "What is the advantage of passing by reference to `shared_ptr` over passing by value to `shared_ptr` directly?" And the Answer would be: It's cheaper.

Comment: To the compiler, they are both different types. You can't really compare Apples and Oranges. **`Test&`** and **`shared_ptr<Test>&`** aren't the same *reference types*. As for performance cost of obtaining the former from the latter, its probably just the cost of an additional indirection. But the latter carries a bit more information

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as if you asked the advantage of passing a reference to a pointer vs passing a reference to an object.  If you want to change the object that's being pointed to, ref the pointer. If you just want to change the object itself, use the direct ref; it's cheaper *and* less restrictive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* reason a function should accept a `std::shared_ptr` as a argument is if it may need to share or modify the **ownership** of the resource. If not, don't pass a `std::shared_ptr`.

If the function will *definitely* need to take shared ownership then it should accept a `std::shared_ptr` by value. Only accept a `std::shared_ptr&` if  the function may or may not take shared ownership.

If the function does not modify *ownership* then pass a *reference* to the resource, not a `std::shared_ptr`.

**See:** *CppCoreGuidelines:* [F.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-smart), [R.30](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-smartptrparam), [R.34](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r34-take-a-shared_ptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-is-part-owner), [R.35](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r35-take-a-shared_ptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-might-reseat-the-shared-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look inside your functions. For `initmem1`, the code usually looks like

```
initMem1(myMem& mInput){ _mem1 = mInput; }
```

We can see the call of an assignment operator, which usually copies all myMem fields.

For initMem2, there are two cases

1)

```
initMem2(shared_ptr<myMem> &pmInput){
     _mem2 = pmInput;
 }
```

You should use 'initMem2(const shared_ptr &pmInput)'. It's a good style.
We can see the fast initialization here. Just links are copied. But you get ownership sharing. If you change `pmInput` outside then `_mem2` changes too.
No copy cunstructor is needed. Both smart ptrs holds the unique object.

2)

```
initMem2(const shared_ptr<myMem> &pmInput){ // of course, const
     _mem2.reset(*pmInput);
 }
```

You create a new shared_ptr with new content originally copied from `pmInput`.
You can change `pmInput` and `_mem2` independently. But you get additional "new/delete calls" for this new shared_ptr and the copy constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

One use case is when the original `shared_ptr` can change its contents in the middle of the function (perhaps a nested call) and the function is prepared to it and wants the new contents.